# Strange output from truffle migrate --network live --dry-run

Tags: contract-development, truffle, contract-deployment, truffle-migration, infura

I can't get my contract to deploy successfully using Infura, MetaMask, and Truffle.

When I run `truffle migrate --network live` I get this error:

`Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful transactions manually.
insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

But then, if I run `truffle migrate --network live --dry-run` I get this output:

`sender doesn't have enough funds to send tx. The upfront cost is: 672197500000000000 and the sender's account only has: 60000000000000000`

Assuming that value is in wei, why would it cost so much to deploy a contract? What can I do about this?

Here is my `truffle.js` file:

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var mnemonic = "my_mnemonic";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    live: {
      network_id: 1,
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://mainnet.infura.io/my_api_key")    
    }   
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you sending ether at deploy time as well? It would help if you posted your code.

Comment: @AdamKipnis Nope. Good point, I posted my contract's code.

Comment: @vipertherapper unrelated to your question, but unless you use `msg.value` in a function, you shouldn't make that function `payable`. That keyword means that you can send ETH to the contract with the transaction, but your `returnEth`, and `fee` don't do that - only `adopt` expects ETH to be sent to it

Comment: @Andrey thanks for pointing that out. So I should just remove `payable` from `returnEth` and `fee`? What are the implications of leaving the `payable` keyword in those functions?

Comment: The implications are that someone can send eth when calling those functions, and that eth will be stuck in the contract, as the contract has no way of returning it back to the caller or the owner

Comment: @AdamKipnis Any idea why this requires so much eth to deploy?

Comment: I'm starting to think that it's both a misleading error message and Ismael's answer is correct (sorry Ismael). I was able to reproduce the same issue in Rinkeby. When the deployment fails, it always uses the same value for the upfront cost, even though that's not your actual cost if successful. Since you only have 0.06 eth in your account, your costs are exceeded your funds (3M gas at 20 Gwei is ~0.06 eth). Try a really low gas price (~2 Gwei) and rerun. It may take a while to mine, but it should work.

Comment: @AdamKipnis I'll try that. Should I use the same 4M for gas that Ismael suggested?

Comment: Yes. Whatever is unused will be returned to you. You can expect the deployment will cost roughly 0.006 eth (or ~$5 US).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use remix.ethereum.org to test your contract and calculate gas usage. For me it uses 2M gas approx when deploying.

You did not specify the gas limit in your config it will use de default (it was around 6.7M gas). You can try lowering it in your truffle.js.

```
var HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");

var mnemonic = "my_mnemonic";

module.exports = {
  networks: {
    live: {
      network_id: 1,
      provider: new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, "https://mainnet.infura.io/my_api_key"),
      gas: "4000000",           // 4M
      gasPrice: "20000000000"   // 20gwei
    }   
  }
};
```

Comment: I thought the same thing, but the same error (with the same cost) is thrown regardless of the gas/gasPrice set in `truffle.js`. Plus, even with those parameters, the cost should be much less (total <.03 eth @20 Gwei).

Comment: @AdamKipnis I'd have to agree with you. I'm at a loss here. I'm trying to understand why this is happening.